# JavaScript syntax document.tags vs document.getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript

I found an awkward shortcut syntax in the [W3.org website](https://www.w3.org/Submission/1996/1/WD-jsss-960822) for JavaScript the document is about styling with JavaScript and the example is

```
document.tags.H1.color = "blue"
```

When I tried it, it didn't work. The syntax I know much:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('h1').item(0).style.color = 'blue'
```

Works fine.

I assume that because the first syntax is present on the W3C website, it is good so why is it not working when I try it. Thanks.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document for an accurate documentation on the object `Document`.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0]` - plural and array notation is the usual way

Comment: *"I assume that because the first syntax is present on the W3C website, it is good"* What you've found is an "initial proposal" for something that didn't end up happening. If it's not at *least* a "Working Draft", it's probably nothing to pay much attention to. As @Zenoo pointed out, MDN has very good info (most of the time). There's also the [WHAT-WG spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-document-object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The W3.org document you looked at is only a proposal. It was the proposal for JavaScript-based stylesheet technology proposed in the 1990s, as an alternative to CSS. This never got accepted. It was implemented in a few browsers back then but you can't expect it to work on modern browsers.
Source: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Style_Sheets

Comment: "in a few browsers back then" — Only Netscape 4.x IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Just because a document is listed on the W3C website does not mean that it is currently, or ever was, fully vetted or even implemented in any major or minor browsers.

I'm not an expert concerning the specs, but W3C documents have statuses for different levels of maturity and acceptance, like Working Draft and Reccomendation. This document you reference was written in 1996 and is listed as an Initial Proposal (even section 9 state "This section is unfinished") - two factors that may affect its practical application in browsers these days.

You may be able to download a browser release from 1996-1999 which implements this, but reference current W3C recommendations and drafts, as well as existing documentation like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document), for contemporary learning and implementation.